# AWS ECR image available in EC2 CLI docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I pushed a Docker image into an AWS ECR. Is there a way to also make it available in the EC2 instance associated with this repository (i.e. usable with the various `docker` CLI commands)?

As an example when I run `docker images` I don't view a new image I just pushed using `docker push <Repository URI>` in the list of images

Comment: You need to `docker run` or `docker pull` it the same way you would any other image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have pushed a Image to ECS , you will have to pull the image to run it as a container. This can be done on any instance or your local machine. For doing this you can follow :

```
1. aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region <region> --profile <profile_name>
2. Cope the output from above and paste + enter
3. Pull the image finally as --> docker pull 501429058813.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/main:v1.0.0
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I thought that it would be automatic but well :) Still uploading my latest image to ECR, will test & approve when done